# How do I make website header logo to be full width on mobile only?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive-design, responsive-images

I am trying to make my mobile logo larger on our site. The logo is perfect for desktop, but on mobile it is very small, regardless of theme settings I tweak.

[image: mobile preview of website]

I tried this snippet in additional CSS without luck:

`

```
/* MOBILE LOGO HEADER */
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {#logo-container img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
}
```

`

Comment: What you need to do depends totally on the HTML and CSS you're using. To have the image in your question is nice, as an illustration, but it doesn't tell us what we need to know to answer your question.

Comment: The CSS rule you've posted will work for the image. However, if the container the image is in is not full width, then it will only take 100% of the width of that container. You'll need to traverse up the DOM until each parent container is set to 100% width until you have your result. There may also be margins and padding also affecting it. We'll never know unless you post the relevant code.

Comment: It will work only when the logo doesn't have huge margin/padding by default. or if the parent elements have huge margin/padding, it won't work either.

Comment: [@Zay City](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20409510/zay-city) Are you able to inspect the header logo and share the screenshot of it? It would be better if you can share the header code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){ 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this following CSS code to change your logo size on mobile.
/* It means on screens that are  640px or less, set logo image width 50% and margin and padding auto means on center.*/

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){

.header-logo img {

width:50%!important;

margin:auto;

padding:auto;

}

}